# Managing Celery Task Results

Tags: python, redis, celery, task-queue

I am pretty new to Celery and I thought I had read somewhere that the task results only stay around for a limited time.  However my backend (redis) is getting pretty bloated after running a lot of tasks through it.

Is there a way to set a TTL on task results or is this something I need to manually purge (and how)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the celery documentation you can completely ignore all results using [`CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-ignore-result).

You can also expire results after a set amount of time using [`CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires), which defaults to 1 day. In the notes it says this should just work with the redis backend, whereas some of the other backends require `celery beat` to be running.

There is also the [`CELERY_MAX_CACHED_RESULTS`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-cache-max) setting that caches up to 5,000 results by default.

Comment: `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` should actually be `CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES`. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html